# Left margin alignment of a container inside a 6 column bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, containers

I have two 6 column bootstrap divs side by side in a row div and both of the divs have an image to display where each image has a width of half the view-port. I have a header and a link to be placed in the left column above the image (I have the image set as background of the column via CSS). I have placed the header and the link in a container.

**Problem**

container doesn't align with the left margin of the text (inside a container) that follows the two 6 column bootstrap divs. I had set margin left for the container but the alignment goes off when the screen size is changed. But below 992px of resolution break-point everything is fine as the columns are stacked. Did I miss something or did I do something wrong?

I'm new to this trade so, help much appreciated!!
Here's the code

```css
#aboutus {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/946/381");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="aboutus" class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 style="color: white;">About Us</h2>
      <a class="small" href="#home" style="color: white;">Home</a>
      <i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/946/381" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     Dignissimos cupiditate ut nobis unde ipsa eius commodi, 
     praesentium eum. Natus, laborum illo est dolorem rem quos 
     ui ipsum nemo fuga. Odio, aut. Esse veniam quia corporis 
     dolor vitae totam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide image of your want, so we will help you !

Comment: I have a random image link as the source for the image in the code above!!

Answer (score 0):

Change col-lg-6 to some other responsive size.

In the example I changed it to col-6.
See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

```css
#aboutus {
  background-color: #e6603f;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/946/381);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div id="aboutus" class=" col-6">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 style="color: white">About Us</h2>
      <a class="small" href="#home" style="color:white">Home</a>
      <i style="color: white" class="fa fa-angle-right">                </i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/946/381" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     Dignissimos cupiditate ut nobis unde ipsa eius commodi, 
     praesentium eum. Natus, laborum illo est dolorem rem quos 
     ui ipsum nemo fuga. Odio, aut. Esse veniam quia corporis 
     dolor vitae totam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `xs` is not available in **bootstrap-4** so check your answer again

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't solve my problem. I need the two images side by side in large screen resolution and to stack in resolutions below large screen.

Comment: What I've observed is that the container div sets its margin relative to its parent, here being the 6 col div in large screen res which has half the width of the view-port. But, in md, sm and xs resolutions, the column takes full width of the view-port, which makes the container div set margin relative to the view-port.

Comment: @AmeerJahan Ive added a second image, let me know if this is still not working for you.

Comment: @MattBunch What is the point of adding second image. I think you did not understand what I'm trying to achieve. I'll try to make a jsfiddle. Thanks!!

Comment: @AmeerJahan I didnt understand that the other image was set to the background via css. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for small screen you need to use col-* class and after large screen you need to use col-lg-* class, for more info check this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

In your code i use `col-12` and `col-lg-6` so in large screen your two image show side by side and in small screen it show like up down manner

```css
#aboutus {
  background-color: #e6603f;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row m-0">
  <div id="aboutus" class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 style="color: white;">About Us</h2>
      <a class="small" href="#home" style="color: white;">Home</a>
      <i style="color: white;" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/946/381" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     Dignissimos cupiditate ut nobis unde ipsa eius commodi, 
     praesentium eum. Natus, laborum illo est dolorem rem quos 
     ui ipsum nemo fuga. Odio, aut. Esse veniam quia corporis 
     dolor vitae totam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need the images side by side in large screens and stack in resolutions below large screens.
What I've observed is that the container div sets its margin relative to its parent, here being the 6 col div in large screen res which has half the width of the view-port. But, in md, sm and xs resolutions, the column takes full width of the view-port, which makes the container div set margin relative to the view-port.